# How to test OCSP implementation?

Tags: java, security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ocsp

For testing ocsp implementation I need a ocsp responder. Is there any ready responder for testing purposes? Or is there any way to run some responder on local host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have or get **openssl**, it **includes a basic but usable OCSP responder**; see man ocsp(1) (sometimes 1ssl or similar) on your system [or on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ocsp.html) at "OCSP Server Options" about halfway down. (The `ocsp` command also includes a client/requester and debugging utility.)

This is designed to support certificates issued (and optionally revoked) by the openssl `ca` command (q.v.) and recorded in its 'database', but that database is just a tab-delimited text file (conventionally but not necessarily named `index.txt`) that you can cons up for certs that already exist as long as they all have the same issuer name. And of course you need a key/cert/chain supporting OCSP-sign for the issuer (or delegate). I thought there was doc on the 'database' format but I can't find it, and I've been using them so long I forget where I learned -- it might have been from the code. But for an example of (re)creating `index.txt` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320038/easy-rsa-index-txt-serial-and-duplicates (answer partly mine).

Note that one process uses one 'database' file and supports one issuer. If you need more than one issuer, you could run several processes on different ports and/or different addresses on a machine with mutiple addresses. If that's not suitable you could put any HTTP frontend in between, e.g. httpd or nginx could accept mixed requests and forward `http://myocsp.local/forCA1` to one `openssl ocsp` process on `localhost:1001` and `http://myocsp.local/forCA2` to another on `localhost:1002` etc.