# How to make openssl ocsp responder busy

Tags: openssl, pyopenssl, ocsp

I am new to ssl environment, please bear with me.

The information what I know I am putting here.

By reading the different page of openssl OCSP

- https://raymii.org/s/articles/OpenSSL_Manually_Verify_a_certificate_against_an_OCSP.html
- https://akshayranganath.github.io/OCSP-Validation-With-Openssl/
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ocsp.html

I started the server successfully for one issuer by understanding from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877330/358458.

> Note that one process uses one 'database' file and supports one
> issuer. If you need more than one issuer, you could run several
> processes on different ports and/or different addresses on a machine
> with multiple addresses.

I have two basic questions, please correct me the questions are invalid.

1. Is OCSP responder is same for multiple issuers? If so how to make OCSP responder busy?
2. If not how to make singe issuer responder busy? using any script or more number of requests to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand 'make busy'. If you are looking to perform a denial of service attack, look elsewhere.

It is true that `openssl ocsp` only supports *one* issuer per launch, or port in your case. Also, it only supports *one* request at a time on said port. `openssl ocsp` is only designed as an example/reference/test responder, not a production OCSP responding server. There are ways around this however;

- Use a different OCSP responder server program (easiest)
- Use the `openssl ocsp -multi` argument to launch a threaded OCSP responder that is capable of handling multiple simultaneous requests (still, only one issuer per instance)
- Use the the `-reqin` and `-respout` arguments detailed in `man ocsp` to process requests on the filesystem instead of launching a full responder. With this, you can use a http server, CGI, and a script to parse the issuer hash field of the OCSP request to tailor your configuration and response to a specific issuer, all from one address/location. This is what I do, and it is no picnic, but you can achieve production load and availability this way if desired.